# Distance and font sizes between two minipages

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, fontsize, minipage

Question 1: How can I increase the distance between two parts of mini page?

Question 2: In the second part of mini page I found that the font size is small as compared to the first part. What is the problem?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\begin{flalign*}
f(x_1)&=f(2.5)&\\[6pt]
&=(2.5)^3-4(2.5)-9&\\[6pt]
&=15.625-10-9&\\[6pt]
&=-3.375\;\;(-ve)&
\end{flalign*}      
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1cm,y=1cm]
\draw [line width=1pt] (-3,-1)-- (3,-1);
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw [fill=black] (-3,-1) circle (2.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (-3.00,-0.5) node {$a=2$};
\draw[color=black] (-3.00,-1.5) node {$(-)$};
\draw [fill=black] (3,-1) circle (2.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (3,-0.50) node {$b=3$};
\draw[color=black] (3,-1.50) node {$(+)$};
\draw [fill=black] (0,-1) circle (2.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (-0.00,-0.5) node {$x_1=2.5$};
\draw[color=black] (-0.00,-1.5) node {$(-)$};
\end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You do say `\begin{scriptsize} ... \end{scriptsize}` in the second minipage, don't you?

Comment: To 1: "two parts" you mean "two mini pages", right? You can use `\hspace{<value>}` between them.

Comment: To 2: As @Gum already said you are chaning the font size. Also `scriptsize` is not an environment but a command, so use `\scriptsize` instead. For TikZ you should use the `font=\scriptsize` key in the TikZ options anyway.

Comment: @MartinScharrer So next is what ? Sir

Comment: @snehal: See my extended answer below. Should you need more, just mentioned it in a comment there or update your question description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add some horizontal space between two minipages you can use `\hfill` to fill the space completly or add an `\hspace{<length>}` between them. Make sure there is no empty line there to avoid a paragraph break.

If you want to have identical font size remove the `scriptsize` environment. It is wrong anyway, as `\scriptsize` is a macro, not an environment (but, unfortunatly, macro names can be used as environemnts with LaTeX without causing errors). Also for TikZ there is the `font=<code>` option key which should be used instead.

Here my suggestion:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{lipsum}% for example fill text
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\par\noindent% to avoid the paragaph indent
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\begin{flalign*}
f(x_1)&=f(2.5)&\\[6pt]
&=(2.5)^3-4(2.5)-9&\\[6pt]
&=15.625-10-9&\\[6pt]
&=-3.375\;\;(-ve)&
\end{flalign*}      
\end{minipage}%
\hfill% to fill in the maximum amount of space or \hspace{<value>}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1cm,y=1cm%,font=\scriptsize
]
\draw [line width=1pt] (-3,-1)-- (3,-1);
\draw [fill=black] (-3,-1) circle (2.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (-3.00,-0.5) node {$a=2$};
\draw[color=black] (-3.00,-1.5) node {$(-)$};
\draw [fill=black] (3,-1) circle (2.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (3,-0.50) node {$b=3$};
\draw[color=black] (3,-1.50) node {$(+)$};
\draw [fill=black] (0,-1) circle (2.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (-0.00,-0.5) node {$x_1=2.5$};
\draw[color=black] (-0.00,-1.5) node {$(-)$};
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{minipage}
\par\bigskip\par
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of MWE]

Comment: It is working properly in fact whatever i want. Millions Trillions thanks.